# how to write Junit for spring scs initialized Ktable Store

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am not able to access store using TopologyTestDriver if I materialized Store with spring scs properties
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.process-in-1.consumer.materializedAs: incoming-store

how to query store in junit using kafka-utils-test for scs initialized store?